# E-Commerce REST API for categories

Tags: rest, uri, e-commerce

In my e-commerce project, I am building a set of REST APIs to list the categories and products from the catalog management system. A category can have sub-categories and a product can belong to a category or stand by itself.

```
- root_category
   - sub_category
      - product1
   - product2
- product3
```

Here in this example, `root_category` contains `sub_category` & `product2`. The `subcategory` contains `product1`. `product3` doesn't belong to any category.

Here are the possible use cases:

1. List all the products in the system.

`/products`

2. Get product details by id.

`/products/{id}`

3. Search for products by id, name or description (need to query by one of these criteria)

`/products?searchTem={searchTerm}&q=[byId|byName|byDescription]`

4. List all categories in the system.

`/categories`

5(a). List sub categories belonging to a particular category.

`/categories/{id}/categories`

5(b). List root level categories. (eg. `root_category`).

`/categories/@root/categories`

6(a). List products belonging to a category.

`/categories/{id}/products`

6(b). List products that don't belong to any category. ie., root level products (eg. `product3`).

`/categories/@root/products`

Please let me know your comments and suggest improvements for these REST URIs listed above. I am a little concerned about 5(b) and 6(b).Can those URIs be designed in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that looks reasonable, the only issue I have is the use of category id.

I would prefer to see a category name used, which is more user-friendly.

Category name has to be unique obviously.